# Difficulties to create a bag after a join with Pig Apache

Tags: hadoop, join, apache-pig

I need to denormalize a part of my data. I have some data donnees_porteur (in JSON) where I want to integrate donnees_enfant (in CSV)

```
donnees_enfant = LOAD '/user/cloudera/enfn.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (NUM_CART_enf,NUM_ENFN,ANNEES_NAIS);   
donnees_porteur = LOAD '/user/cloudera/part*' USING JsonLoader();
```

EDIT :

```
    donnees_porteur: {
Id: bytearray,
Infos: (cod_civl: bytearray,lb_civl: bytearray,nom: bytearray,prnm: bytearray,age: bytearray),
Geo: (cod_regn: bytearray,cod_depr: bytearray,cod_comm: bytearray,cp: bytearray,lb_comm: bytearray,cod_npai: bytearray,dt_npai: bytearray,email: bytearray),
Socio: (nb_enf: bytearray,cod_socio: bytearray,lb_socio: bytearray,cod_socio_conj: bytearray,lb_socio_conj: bytearray,cod_sit_faml: bytearray,lb_sit_faml: bytearray),
Segm: {(cod_segm: bytearray,cod_typ_segm: bytearray,dat_deb: bytearray,dat_fin: bytearray)}}
```

-- I do the join between the porteur and the enfant (cardinality 1,n):

```
test= FOREACH 
    (JOIN donnees_porteur BY Id LEFT, donnees_enfant BY NUM_CART_enf) 
    GENERATE donnees_porteur::Id AS ID, 
    {(donnees_enfant::NUM_CART_enf,donnees_enfant::NUM_ENFN)} AS ENFANT:{(id_enf,numero)};
```

-- I group By to have all enfants of a porteur in only one row

```
test2 = GROUP test BY ID;
```

-- I obtain a bag with differente tuple of porteur with one enfant each. So I need to reconstruct the line. I try with :

```
test3= FOREACH test2 GENERATE test;
```

but it's not good.

**Result test2 :**

```
(0,{(0,{(0,2)}),(0,{(0,3)}),(0,{(0,1)})})
(1,{(1,{(1,3)}),(1,{(1,1)}),(1,{(1,2)})})
(2,{(2,{(2,1)}),(2,{(2,2)})})
```

**But I want to obtain :**

```
(0,({(0,2),(0,3),(0,1)}))
(1,({(1,3),(1,1),(1,2)}))
(2,({(2,1),(2,2)}))
```

Can you help me ?

---

edit :

I post an "easy" example of my problem.

This is the real test :

```
denorm2 = FOREACH (JOIN donnees_porteur BY Id LEFT, donnees_enfant BY NUM_CART_enf) GENERATE donnees_porteur::Id AS ID, 
    donnees_porteur::Infos AS INFOS, 
    donnees_porteur::Geo AS Geo,
    donnees_porteur::Segm AS Segm,
    {(donnees_enfant::NUM_CART_enf,donnees_enfant::NUM_ENFN)} AS ENFANT:{(id_enf,numero)};
```

with ID as the field, 
INFOS, GEO, as tuple,
Segm as a bag like ENFANT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was stranded with my method because of the bag segm.

In fact, in my version of pig, the GROUP BY bag is not yet supported.

So I change the way :

```
donnees_porteur = LOAD '/user/cloudera/part*' USING JsonLoader();

donnees_enfant = LOAD '/user/cloudera/enfn.csv' USING PigStorage(';') AS (id_enf,num,annee);

group_enfant_by_id = GROUP donnees_enfant BY id_enf;

test= FOREACH (JOIN donnees_porteur BY Id LEFT, group_enfant_by_id BY group) GENERATE  Id AS Id, 
        Infos as Infos,
        Geo AS Geo,
        Socio AS Socio,
        pdv AS pdv,
        Segm as Segm,
        group_enfant_by_id::donnees_enfant.(num,annee) AS Enfn;

STORE test INTO '' USING JsonStorage();
```

Thanks for the tips !

Answer (score 1):

test3=FOREACH test2 GENERATE $0, $1.ENFANT;

test3 will have the group and only the ENFANT part

Comment: It works well on my little example. Thanks ! But, if I have more things, like :  `test= FOREACH (JOIN donnees_porteur BY Id LEFT, donnees_enfant BY NUM_CART_enf) GENERATE donnees_porteur::Id AS ID,
donnees_porteur::Infos AS INFOS, (donnees_enfant::NUM_CART_enf,donnees_enfant::NUM_ENFN) AS enfant:(id_enf,num_enf);`, I use : `test3 = FOREACH test2 GENERATE $0 as id, $1.INFOS, $1.enfant;` and now, I have duplicated fields INFOS (I have the same than enfant. Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
test= FOREACH 
    (JOIN donnees_porteur BY Id LEFT, donnees_enfant BY NUM_CART_enf) 
    GENERATE 
        donnees_porteur::Id AS ID, 
        donnees_enfant::NUM_CART_enf AS id_enf,
        donnees_enfant::NUM_ENFN AS numero;

test2 = GROUP test BY ID;
test3 = FOREACH test2 
           GENERATE 
               group AS ID, 
               test.(id_enf,numero);
```

Comment: grunt> describe test2     ///////////            
test2: {group: bytearray,test: {(ID: bytearray,enfant: (id_enf: bytearray,num_enf: bytearray))}}          //////////   So when I try :      //////     grunt> test3 = FOREACH test2 
>>            GENERATE 
>>                group AS ID, 
>>                test.(id_enf,numero);
2014-08-21 00:41:40,159 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1128: Cannot find field id_enf in ID:bytearray,enfant:tuple(id_enf:bytearray,num_enf:bytearray)
 ////////////// I have an error :/

Comment: Updated my answer. Unless you have specific reason to pack id_enf and numero inside a tuple, which is wrapped inside a bag, above code should work fine.

Comment: It works, thanks. But now if I complexify the scheme, I have still difficulties. If I add another tuple like INFOS with cardinality (1,1) with the PORTEUR, the informations are duplicated (if there are 3 ENFANTs, there are 3 same INFOS). I edit my question. But thanks I improve ! `grunt> test3 = FOREACH test2 GENERATE group AS ID, (test::INFOS), test.(id_enf,numero) AS enfant;` don't work

Comment: Sorry, I could not understand the edited question. If possible, can you please explain your question (after edit) again - preferably with simple relation names A, B and C :)

Comment: Looks like you came up with your answer. Cool!